# Jquery Tablesorter plugin and drag/drop functionality

Tags: jquery, tablesorter, droppable

Im using the Jquery Tablesorter plugin on a site Im building and have encountered an issue with dragging and dropping content using the Jquery draggable and droppable functions.

If the table has 20 rows and I have set the table to only display 10 rows per page I have found that I can drag in and out of the tables first page, however as soon as I page to the second page I loose the ability to drag and drop.

Any help would be great.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#news-table") 
.tablesorter({widthFixed: false, widgets: ['zebra']}) 
.tablesorterPager({container: $("#pager"), size: 5});
});
</script>
```

This is the script to initialize the table. And this is a row from the table. Images with the class 'news_draggable' are the elements that can be dragged.

```
<div style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" class="droppable ui-droppable" id="target_11">
<img src="../uploads/thumb_p16t4fe2urr012g31e671garcto7.jpg" class="news_draggable ui-draggable" id="11">
</div>
```

I think that the draggable function needs to be called when the table is changed, either by clicking to another page or by sorting the table. Im just unsure how that would be achieved.

Comment: what you have tried so far ? show some code

Answer (score 0):

The pager plugin stores and sorts the data from memory, so the rows from the second page don't actually exist after the pager plugin has initialized. You could either *not use* the pager addon or try the modified version of the pager I have in my github fork of [tablesorter](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/index.html).

Here is the [pager addon](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/example-pager.html) demo page. Just set the `removeRows` option to `false` and it should resolve this issue.